# Scapy verbose mode documentation

Tags: python, documentation, scapy, verbose

I understand that:

```
conf.verb = 0
```

Disables Scapy verbose mode but where is the documentation to confirm this?

My googling has failed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `conf`'s docstring specifies that configuring `conf.verb = 0` sets the level of verbosity to *almost mute*, which implies that it doesn't disable it altogether.

The relevant excerpt from the docstring is as follows:

```
verb     : level of verbosity, from 0 (almost mute) to 3 (verbose)
```

Here is the entire docstring:

```
In [1]: from scapy.all import conf
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)

In [2]: conf?
Type:       Conf
String Form:
ASN1_default_codec = <ASN1Codec BER[1]>
           AS_resolver = <scapy.as_resolvers.AS_resolver_multi insta <...> alse
           use_pcap   = False
           verb       = 2
           version    = '2.3.2'
           warning_threshold = 5
           wepkey     = ''
File:       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/config.py
Docstring:
This object contains the configuration of scapy.
session  : filename where the session will be saved
interactive_shell : If set to "ipython", use IPython as shell. Default: Python 
stealth  : if 1, prevents any unwanted packet to go out (ARP, DNS, ...)
checkIPID: if 0, doesn't check that IPID matches between IP sent and ICMP IP citation received
           if 1, checks that they either are equal or byte swapped equals (bug in some IP stacks)
           if 2, strictly checks that they are equals
checkIPsrc: if 1, checks IP src in IP and ICMP IP citation match (bug in some NAT stacks)
check_TCPerror_seqack: if 1, also check that TCP seq and ack match the ones in ICMP citation
iff      : selects the default output interface for srp() and sendp(). default:"eth0")
verb     : level of verbosity, from 0 (almost mute) to 3 (verbose)
promisc  : default mode for listening socket (to get answers if you spoof on a lan)
sniff_promisc : default mode for sniff()
filter   : bpf filter added to every sniffing socket to exclude traffic from analysis
histfile : history file
padding  : includes padding in desassembled packets
except_filter : BPF filter for packets to ignore
debug_match : when 1, store received packet that are not matched into debug.recv
route    : holds the Scapy routing table and provides methods to manipulate it
warning_threshold : how much time between warnings from the same place
ASN1_default_codec: Codec used by default for ASN1 objects
mib      : holds MIB direct access dictionnary
resolve   : holds list of fields for which resolution should be done
noenum    : holds list of enum fields for which conversion to string should NOT be done
AS_resolver: choose the AS resolver class to use
extensions_paths: path or list of paths where extensions are to be looked for

In [3]:
```

Comment: Where can I find the docstring?

Comment: In the file `config.py` in _scapy_'s installation dir. On my machine (_Ubuntu_) it's in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/config.py`. Alternatively, you can also import `conf` and print `conf.__doc__`.