# Why 'int' object is not callable?

Tags: python-3.x

```
try:
    from logging import getLogger, ERROR
    getLogger('scapy.runtime').setLevel(ERROR)
    from scapy.all import *
    conf.verb(0)
except ImportError:
    print("[!]failed to import scapy")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dontalion/Desktop/python-programming/untitled/test-mitm.py", line 10, in <module>
    conf.verb(0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: It's not helpful that your example has nine lines but the error reported is in line 10. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps mean to do `conf.verb = 0`? `conf.verb` is an integer, so you cannot call it like a function as you are doing with `conf.verb(0)`. You can see this in the source code [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/4addf526df551ecc7ea04f79035f87675a6831a7/scapy/config.py#L556).

There's also [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39635324/9374673) about setting Scapy's verbosity to 0.